# Clean the csv data using python

Tags: python

I tried to remove the unwanted characters / # http form each line
codes below:

```
import csv

with open('C:\\project\\in.csv','r') as input_file:  

    with open('C:\\project\\out.csv','w') as output_file:             

        for L in input_file:    

            if L.endswith("/"):
                newL=L.replace("/","") 
                output_file.write(newL)           

            elif L.find("#"):
                newL,sep,tail=L.partition("#")
                output_file.write(newL)           

            elif L.startswith('http:'):
                newL=L.replace('http:','https:')
                output_file.write(newL)
```

here is the mini example in.csv file for testing:

```
line1/
line2#sdgsgs
https://line3
http://line4
line5/
```

after make clean, I want it to be like :

```
line1
line2
https://line3
https://line4
line5
```

But the result not what I want, Can some one give me a hand.

Many Thanks, Henry

Comment: Did you look at what is in `L` for each line?

Comment: Thank you so much Scott, I have 2 more questions regarding this mini project. Say if I have three lines as below  line 6

Comment: If you have more questions, post them as questions.

Answer (score 1):

In this version a line can contain all of the replacement chars:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv

Output = []
with open('C:\\project\\in.csv', 'r') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        line = line.strip()

        if line.endswith("/"):
            line = line.replace("/", "")

        if "#" in line:
            line, sep, tail = line.partition("#")

        if line.startswith('http:'):
            line = line.replace('http:', 'https:')

        Output.append(line)

with open('C:\\project\\out.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    for output in Output:
        output_file.write("{}\n".format(output))
```

Will output:

```
line1
line2
https://line3
https://line4
line5
```

Comment: `if line.find("#")` is problematic: it will return `-1` if not found and `bool(-1)` evaluates to True in the conditional statement.  That is why the succeeding `elif` didn't work in the original. The mutually exclusive `elif` structure could be kept by changing that check to `if '#' in L:`

Comment: Thank you so much Master "what", I have 2 more questions regarding this mini project. Say if I have three lines output as   line 6 line6 line6. I want only one line in the out.csv. line6 and  the final line  http:line9#abc, I want the last line as https:line9.    Thanks again in advance!!!